# key.charAt is not a function error in createLocalVue()

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

Using createLocalVue function throws a TypeError: key.charAt is not a function. The interesting thing is that it is thrown only in the case of some components while I use localVue in every components tests. Here is a sample test code:

```
import assign from 'lodash/assign'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import filters from '@/filters'
import { DateUtils } from '@/filters/date-utils'
import TaskCard from '@/components/molecules/TaskCard'
import Icon from '@/components/atoms/Icon'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('TaskCard.vue', () => {
  let wrapper
  const task = {
    Status: 3,
    Name: 'Sample task',
    Deadline: Date.now(),
    Owner: {
      DisplayName: 'Admin'
    },
    Title: 'Sample title'
  }
  const position = 2

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(TaskCard, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        task,
        position
      }
    })
  })

  it('TaskCard should be a Vue instance and should have a div root element with the class "ca-task-card"', () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.is('div')).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.classes()).toContain('ca-task-card')
  })

  it('TaskCard\'s ca-task-order element should have the mocked status prop', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.ca-task-order').find('span').text()).toBe(position.toString())
  })

  it('TaskCard\'s first "p" element should contain the modified task name as text', () => {
    const newTask = assign(task, { Name: 'Sample task name' })
    wrapper.setProps({task: newTask})
    expect(wrapper.findAll('p').at(0).text()).toBe('Sample task name')
  })

  it('TaskCard should have 4 Icon component children', () => {
    expect(wrapper.findAll(Icon).length).toBe(4)
  })

  it('TaskCard should have the formatted deadline of the task in the element with the class "ca-task-card__deadline"', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.ca-task-card__deadline').text()).toBe(DateUtils.formatDate(wrapper.vm.task.Deadline))
  })

  it('TaskCard with completed status should have completed icon and not any others', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.ca-task-card__icon--completed').exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find('.ca-task-card__icon--delegated').exists()).toBe(false)
  })

  it('TaskCard with delegated status should have delegated icon and not any others', () => {
    const newTask = assign(task, {
      Status: 2,
      Name: 'Sample delegated task'
    })
    const newWrapper = mount(TaskCard, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        task: newTask,
        position
      }
    })

    expect(newWrapper.find('.ca-task-card__icon--completed').exists()).toBe(false)
    expect(newWrapper.find('.ca-task-card__icon--delegated').exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

FAIL  test\unit\specs\molecules\TaskCard.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: key.charAt is not a function

   6 | import Icon from '@/components/atoms/Icon'
   7 |
>  8 | const localVue = createLocalVue()
   9 |
  10 | describe('TaskCard.vue', () => {
  11 |   let wrapper

  at Object.has (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js:1932:50)
  at baseGetTag (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:448:48)
  at baseClone (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5047:15)
  at node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5086:31
  at arrayEach (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:4304:9)
  at baseClone (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5080:3)
  at node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5086:31
  at arrayEach (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:4304:9)
  at baseClone (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5080:3)
  at node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5086:31
  at arrayEach (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:4304:9)
  at baseClone (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5080:3)
  at cloneDeep (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5116:10)
  at node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5141:11
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at createLocalVue (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:5137:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/unit/specs/molecules/TaskCard.spec.js:8:46)
```

Comment: What's in `@/filters`? For me, this error showed up because I have `Vue.use(PortalVue)` in my test setup, even though my component under test wasn't using it. Currently working around it by using `jest.mock('portal-vue')`.

Comment: I think the problem was that I have to use shallowMount to stub the Icon component to find it.

Comment: You don't have to use `shallowMount` to stub components; you can stub select components with `mount` as well. Giving your component a name (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#name) will allow you to find and stub the component in tests.